# httpd running internally but not externally

Tags: apache, networking, centos

I have a new server running CentOS, and it has httpd running on `192.168.1.100:80`.
I can connect to my server through ssh on `192.168.1.100`, but when I go to `192.168.1.100` in my browser, it says `"Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 192.168.1.100".`
I also tried wget to see if that works, and here is where it gets interesting.
when I run:

```
wget 192.168.1.100
```

On my server it gets the index.html file as it should.
but when I run it on my laptop is says `"Connecting to 192.168.1.100:80... failed: No route to host."`
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your Apache configuration binds httpd to 192.168.1.100:80
Find line `Listen 192.168.1.100:80` in Apache main configuration - something like `/etc/httpd/httpd.conf` or `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and change this line to `Listen 0.0.0.0:80`.
Restart Apache and it will probably work.